# How can I resolve Memory Quota Exceed and Request Timeout errors on Heroku? Rails Web API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I launched an app today. After about 10 hours, once enough people had signed up and were using the application, the app came to a standstill.

I'm getting 3 types of errors:

H12: Request Timeout
R14: Memory Quota Exceeded
H13: Connection Closed Without Response

I've had 361 memory errors in the last 4 hours, and 674 Request Timeouts in the last 90 minutes.

I'm really quite unsure about how to tackle server side issues. I my Rails JSON Web API is on Heroku right now.

What's the best way to go about tackling these issues?

Comment: What kind of dyno are you using? With free one you can easily run into these kind of issues. For database you can check [indexes usage](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/indexes-examine.html)

Comment: @Dmitry I have two Standard-1x Dynos runnings. I also have the Standard-0 postgres DB setup, so 1GB Ram, 64 GB Storage, 120 connections.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

1. Since your application is running out of memory, one strategy would be to run less processes-per-dyno. In your web sever configuration (`Procfile`), how are you running your app? A single thread? Multiple? If multiple, try lowering that number. This will use less memory, and will make your processes more stable.
2. To handle the 'Connection Closed Without Response' errors, you'll probably need to add more dynos to handle your increase in traffic. What's happening is that your requests are either taking too long to complete (> 30 seconds), or your app is just not finishing the processing of requests due to other issues (memory / cpu / etc).

My instinct tells me that by lowering your process concurrency per dyno, you'll likely get the performance benefits you need to solve all of these issues at once.

Comment: Can you provide details on what to use in a Procfile? Here is what mine looks like. Not sure if I am missing anything. `web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`